# RegEx For Complicated Filenames

Tags: regex

I have tried over the years to make sense of RegEx but it just doesn't click for me. I have a bunch of files in various patterns. I am running Windows 10 and am trying both RegexRenamer and Bulk Rename Utility. Example Files

> File (1982)(Day Storm)(Disk 2 of 2)[1]
>   File Name (Midnight)[a](Tape 1 of 2)(198x)
>   File Name, The (-)(de)(All the Way Home)(Tape 3)

I have been trying to find one statement or the smallest number of statements that will leave only the file name in its three various forms (basically anything not in parentheses), while taking away all parentheses and their contents, excluding any parentheses that includes Tape or Disk. This one takes care of the year: `\((.{4})\)`

I was working on this one to take out everything else: `\((.+)\)|^\((?!\[\D])\)*$`
I just can't seem to wrap my brain around it. I have been reading and now that are talking about lookaheads and look behinds. Can anyone help?

Comment: Why do you want or need regex for this?

Comment: @tripleee OP is using a file name renaming app to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with your application but if lookaheads are supported you should be able to use a negative lookahead to remove `tape` and `disc` matches.

This should work for your:

```
\((?!(Tape|Disk))[^)]+\)
```

replace all matches with nothing.

https://regex101.com/r/vWJloG/2/

Comment: That works and thank you for the help. Now I am trying to understand it.  
\( means it starts with a parentheses  
( begins a group  ?! is saying doesn't contain Tape or Disk  
.* means followed by any number of characters  
[ means one of the following characters  
^ means the start of a string  
) is the character it should look for  
] closes the other [  
+ means any number of occurrences of [^)]  
? means once or none of any number of occurrences of [^)]  
\) means it closes with a parentheses

Comment: `+` means one or more occurrences of the previous character/group. The group in this case is a negated character class which means it will match any characters that are not inside that (in the case a closing parenthesis). The `?` means it stops at the first occurance of the next character. There's a very detailed explanation at the `regex101` link.

Comment: @user1621308 There is no need to add `.*` in the lookahead as you only want to assert Tape or Disk. You also don't have to make the `[^)]+?` non greedy as it can not cross the `)` boundary using the negated character class.

Answer (score 1):

To match the parenthesis that includes either Tape or Disk to be replaced with an empty string and assuming that there can be no char `(` and `)` until the closing parenthesis, you might use:

```
\((?![^()]*\b(Tape|Disk)\b)[^()]*\)
```

*Explanation*

- `\(` Match `(`
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is not

  - `[^()]*` Negated character class, match 0+ occurrences of any char except `(` or `)`
  - `\b(Tape|Disk)\b` Match either Tape or Disk between word boundaries
- `)` Close lookahead
- `[^()]*` Match 0 occurrences of any char except `(` or `)`
- `\)` Match `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vrYmf7/1)

If Tape or Disk should be right after the opening parenthesis:

```
\((?!(Tape|Disk)\b)[^()]*\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DhnNzN/1)

**Note** If you don't want to cross newline boundaries, you could use `[^()\r\n]` for the negated character class.

Comment: This should work in RegexRenamer, but it won't work in Bulk Rename Utility.